# keep the margin when the referenced view is gone in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 TextViews as in the xml below.
If I hide the `textView2` at runtime, I lose the bottom margin.
How can I keep the bottom margin between `textView` and parent to be 16dp when the `textView2` is gone.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:text="abc"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:text="xyz"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Use `layout_goneMarginBottom`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:text="abc"
      app:layout_goneMarginBottom="16dp"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
      />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
      android:text="xyz"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! In my case I was setting `layout_goneMarginTop` in the view I was hiding, instead of setting `layout_goneMarginBottom` in the view that I wanted to stay visible and keep the margin.

Answer (score 14):

Below example helps to understand this concept

[image]

Below are the constraints for **text3**

```
 app:layout_goneMarginStart="100dp"
 app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/text2"
 android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
```

since we had set start constraint with text2 for text3

- when text2 is visible, **android:layout_marginStart="10dp"** will be considered
- when text2 is gone,**app:layout_goneMarginStart="100dp"** will be considered as text3 start constraint is with text2.

So, **when startConstraint is gone it considers goneMarginStart.Similarly,if endConstraint is gone, goneMarginEnd will be considered** as below

[image]

Comment: nice example, thx.