# What does app:layout_goneMarginLeft="" do for views in constraintlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-view, android-constraintlayout

How does the `app:layout_goneMarginLeft` and its variants affect the view arrangements in constraintlayout?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An example for this concept:

Consider `2 TextViews` with ids `textView1` and `textView2` where `textView2` has a 0 dp constraint at the end of `textView1`.

Case 1: When visibility of `textView1` is `VISIBLE`, `textView2` will be just right of `textView1` with a 0 dp margin.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/form_field_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/form_field_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="10dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Result

[image]

Case 2: When visibility of `textView1` is `GONE`, `textView2` will set its marginLeft to 10 dp since I have specified `app:layout_goneMarginLeft="10dp"`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/form_field_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView1"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/form_field_background"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="TextView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        app:layout_goneMarginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="10dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you constrain, for example, a view, B, to another view, A, and at some point in your logic/code you change the visibility of the view A to `view.GONE`, if you use `app:layout_goneMarginLeft=""` for example, it will keep the margins or like said in the documentation:

> you can also indicate a different margin value to be used

You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549516/keep-the-margin-when-the-referenced-view-is-gone-in-constraintlayout).